# Parsing HTML page with HtmlAgilityPack using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, html-agility-pack

How can i parse html using Linq on a webpage and add values to a string. I am using the HtmlAgilityPack on a metro application and would like to bring back 3 values and add them to a string.

here is the url = http://explorer.litecoin.net/address/Li7x5UZqWUy7o1tEC2x5o6cNsn2bmDxA2N

I would like to get the values from the following see "belwo"

"Balance:",
"Transactions in",
"Received"

```
WebResponse x = await req.GetResponseAsync();
HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)x;
if (res != null)
{
    if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        Stream stream = res.GetResponseStream();
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

        string appName = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants // not sure what t
        string a = "Name: " + WebUtility.HtmlDecode(appName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following. You might also consider pulling the table apart as it is a little better formed than the free-text in the 'p' tag.

Cheers, Aaron.

```
// download the site content and create a new html document
// NOTE: make this asynchronous etc when considering IO performance
var url = "http://explorer.litecoin.net/address/Li7x5UZqWUy7o1tEC2x5o6cNsn2bmDxA2N";
var data = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(data);

// extract the transactions 'h3' title, the node we want is directly before it
var transTitle = 
    (from h3 in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("h3")
     where h3.InnerText.ToLower() == "transactions"
     select h3).FirstOrDefault();

// tokenise the summary, one line per 'br' element, split each line by the ':' symbol
var summary = transTitle.PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling;
var tokens = 
    (from row in summary.InnerHtml.Replace("<br>", "|").Split('|')
     where !string.IsNullOrEmpty(row.Trim())
     let line = row.Trim().Split(':')
     where line.Length == 2
     select new { name = line[0].Trim(), value = line[1].Trim() });

// using linqpad to debug, the dump command drops the currect variable to the output
tokens.Dump();
```

'Dump()', is a LinqPad command that dumps the variable to the console, the following is a sample of the output from the Dump command:

- Balance: 5 LTC
- Transactions in: 2
- Received: 5 LTC
- Transactions out: 0
- Sent: 0 LTC

Comment: i do not have the property "Dump" this might be because the app is a windows store app. is there another property i could use?

Comment: The comment above the Dump command explains what I'm doing there. I use LinqPad to debug and run scripts, the Dump method just drops the variable out to the console. I'll edit the answer to show output from the command so you can visualize the results.

Comment: No worries, just remember to mark an answer. Also, I think that @COLD TOLD split the string on the 'br' elements better than I did, I waste a call to Replace, where-as his/hers is more efficient and readable.

Answer (score 1):

the document you have to parse is not the most well formed for parsing many elements are missing the class or at least id attribute but what you want to get is a second p tag
content in it

you can try this

```
HtmlDocument htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);



var pNodes = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p")
[1].InnerHtml.ToString().Split(new string[] { "<br />" }, StringSplitOptions.None).Take(3);

 string vl="Balance:"+pNodes[0].Split(':')[1]+"Transactions in"+pNodes[1].Split(':')[1]+"Received"+pNodes[2].Split(':')[1];
```

Comment: i cant use SelectNodes it is not supported in windows app store dev that is why i was trying to use "Descendants: