# Parsing PHP page for an ios application using Linq and Html Agility Pack

Tags: c#, html, ios, linq, xamarin

```html
<tr id="5" class="altRow ">
    <td>37</td>
    <td>$CUSTOM_MESSAGE_13$</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Hello everyone, I'm working on an iOS application with Xamarin and I need to retrieve a value in a php page and since I can't use Xpath code in Xamarin, I must use Linq to get the value `0` below `$CUSTOM_MESSAGE_13$` in the code above. Can someone help me please?

I tried to use the code below but I don't know how to complete it.

```
var msg =
    (from td in html.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
     where td.InnerText.ToLower() == "$CUSTOM_MESSAGE_13$"
     select td).FirstOrDefault();
var info = msg.ToString();
TextE1.Text = info;
```

I tried to use [this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852762/parsing-html-page-with-htmlagilitypack-using-linq) but I think the problem is that the `0` is in the same node that `$CUSTOM_MESSAGE_13$` and I don't know how to return it.

Another precision, the value I try to return is in a table but I don't know how to extract it.

[Link of the screenshot of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHN0T.png)

Comment: use Skip() in your LINQ to go to the "next" node

Comment: You have a problem where you are using ToLower() and then trying to match an uppercase constant.

Answer (score 0):

Linq isn't the right tool to scan sequentially through data. And theoretically the Descendants() function could return the td elements in any order. But try something like:

```
var tds = html.DocumentNode.Descendants("td").ToArray();
var msg = tds[Array.FindIndex(td => td.ToUpper() == "$CUSTOM_MESSAGE_13$")+1];
var info = msg.ToString();
TextE1.Text = info;
```

Comment: thanks I had the syntax of the find.index function but it I think it'll work.